# Down to what version of IE should I support?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

My jQuery code doesn't work in old IE browsers. Down to what version should I make my website compatible?

This is pretty much the same as [What version of Internet Explorer (IE) should my web app support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687827/what-version-of-internet-explorer-ie-should-my-web-app-support), but that one is from 2010 and I'd like to hear some new opinions.

Note: I intentionally did not mention the version of IE it's working down to, since I'd like a common answer.

Comment: The accepted answer there remains accurate - it depends on your user base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my personal experience, I have found most home users use a modern browser (IE 9, Firefox, Chrome, Safari). Cooperate users are a very different story. They usually use custom, legacy software that prevents them from using newer browsers. There are also still [quite a few people](http://thenextweb.com/microsoft/2012/09/01/windows-7-finally-overtakes-windows-xp-mac-os-x-overtakes-windows-vista/) on Windows XP (around 40%). These are generally older users or lazy super users.

With that said, what audience is your code targeting? I understand that developers will be using it, but is this geared toward enterprises or more consumer-based sites?

All things considered, I would consider IE 6+ if you're targeting corporations. Seeing as this is what [jQuery officially supports](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility), this is the most optimal solution. However, adding IE 6 (and IE 7) compatibility is easier said than done. Therefore, I personally recommend supporting IE 8+ (and Firefox/Chrome/Safari of course). If you want to help forcefully push users off of outdated (and probably vulnerable browsers), you could just leave the IE 8 bugs and say you only support HTML5/CSS3 browsers.